# Using Credential API in .NET. Adding some detalization

Tags: c#, dialog

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa302353) a brief and not-so-bad intro upon using Credential API in .NET. But I want to go deeper into detalization:

[image: Standart credential dialog]

On that figure is displayed a well common login dialog - beside username text box there is seen an disabled button with text [...]
Can anyone tell me how to enable it and handle it's pressing?

Comment: Is there a 'coined a new word' tag?

Comment: What do You mean? that this is not touchable?

Comment: 'detalization' - I'm not even sure what that means. I think it means 'detail'.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'm wrongly asking... In fact You're right - I want to add some additional features to Credential Dialog...

Comment: Thinking upon using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialogWindowsCredentialsClone.aspx) as a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WindowsCredentialsClone.aspx) as solution.